# Samba4: Possible to build a AD Forest

Tags: active-directory, linux-networking, samba4

currently I have to set up a completly new AD infrastructure. Right now most parts in that company are run by NT-DCs untill now.

I bought a new Server installing a Samba 4 (Version 4.3) domain controller on it and started to migrate all user accounts and PCs. Everything works fine.
Now the branch offices should be integrated into this structure as childs with their own DCs.

TL;DR: Is it possible with Samba 4.3 to build a AD-Forest with children? If so: Is a tutorial / guide for this out there?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK this is not supported yet. There is no support of multi domain structure at both core and Samba database levels. Actually, global catalog server feature has not been implemented in Samba (once the connection request is made, it will be then redirected to the LDAP directory instead).

Answer (score 0):

The closest I came to an answer was an archived message to who I imagine is a samba developer on the samba website at https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2016-April/199194.html

The message states

> Samba4 AD currently has only a partial support for inter-forest trust, 
>   so a fortiori it does not support intra-forest trust. So no, you cannot 
>   yet "create a new domain in an existing forest" with Samba4 AD.

Looking at the samba roadmap at https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Roadmap forest trusts do get a mention, but only as one-way and two-way trusts. Intra-Forest trusts don't get a mention however from what I can see.